# Why is HashPartioner needed in the StatefulNetworkWordCount in spark streaming example?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

My Question is regarding the StatefulNetworkWordCount example :

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/StatefulNetworkWordCount.scala

Q1) The stateDstream RDD is maintained by the driver or the worker node or does each worker node has its own local copy of the complete state rdd?

Q2) Why do we need a HashPartitioner in the following line :

`val stateDstream = wordDstream.updateStateByKey[Int](newUpdateFunc,
      new HashPartitioner (ssc.sparkContext.defaultParallelism), true, initialRDD)`

What is happening behind the scenes here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer both of your questions:

**1)** The `RDD`'s produced by `DStream` are distributed across the workers. Similar to non-streaming, this means that records from each `RDD` produced by the `DStream` are spread out across the cluster (which is why partitioning matters here).

**2)** Partitioning is important in this case because it settles how records from every `RDD` iteration are split up. Especially with a transformation like [`updateStateByKey()`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/PairDStreamFunctions.scala#L462), you tend to see keys of `RDD`'s across various batch intervals stay the same. So it goes without saying here that if our keys from each interval `RDD` arrayed across the same partitions, this function can work more efficiently and can update state for a key *within* a partition.

As an example, let us look at the word count program you linked. Let us consider `RDD`'s at two one second intervals (`rdd1` at t=1 and `rdd2` at t=2). Say `rdd1` generated is for the text `"hello world"` and `rdd2` generated also sees the text `"hello I'm world"`. Without partitioning, the records for each `RDD` can be sent to various partitions on various workers (the `"hello"` at t=1 and `"hello"` at t=2 could be sent to separate locations). This implies that an update to the count state would need to reshuffle records on each iteration to obtain the updated count. With a partitioner defined (and remembered as indicated by one of the parameters!), we will see keys `"hello"` and `"world"` at the same partition, thereby avoiding a shuffle, and creating a more efficient update.

It is important to also note here that because keys can change, there is a parameter to toggle whether or not to remember the partitioner.

Comment: So by using partitioner is Spark acting like a distributed store .. like REDIS  . So ideally i should not need a datastore if I am using updateStateByKey() and a hash-partitioner .

Comment: Well... that depends on your use case. Admittedly, I'm not too familiar with REDIS but they seem to have pretty differing use cases: REDIS for quick cached lookups and Spark for data transformation.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I believe using methods like 'updateStateByKey()' enable spark to maintain state and so I want to use it to maintain my application state. Basically I am building an in memory cache. Hence the comparison with a distributed in memory datastore

Comment: Makes sense, though I would caution that with too many keys, your updated `RDD` might spill. Might be worth looking at windowing if that happens.

Comment: Thanks!, sure I will take a look at Windowing too.